# For loop inside for loop causing fails after second loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

Good evening all,

I'm working on a code that checks disk addresses to see if there is a disk present. I verify which disk number it is by executing a scan, disabling the disk, scanning again, and then compare the results to determine the disk, and then re-enable the disk before the loop repeats to scan the next address. As you can see below in my output, it goes through the process, gets scan1 and scan2 for slot 1, which I have printed to show that disk 0 was removed, so that must be the disk in the slot. The loop repeats for the next slot and gets scan1 and scan2 to show that after the removal, disk1 has disappeared, which implies it is in that slot.

However, when I do my second for loop inside to compare the two strings and actually save that difference to a variable, the output for the variable result is just a blank string ' '. Because it is just a blank string, i'm getting the string index out of range error message, which makes sense. I just don't understand how the second for loop inside the main for loop can be fine for one loop, but then when comparing scan1 and scan2 for the second time (even though i can see they're different) it just stores a blank string to result.

```
# Addresses of each populated slot
Slot1PackedAddress = '+-01.0-[82]----00.0'
Slot2PackedAddress = '+-03.0-[84]----00.0'
Slot3PackedAddress = '+-03.0-[08]----00.0'
Slot4PackedAddress = '+-01.0-[01]----00.0'
Addresses = [Slot1PackedAddress, Slot2PackedAddress, Slot3PackedAddress, Slot4PackedAddress]

InitialChecks = [None]*5
diskchange = [0]*5
Slot = [None]*5

SlotOn = ['4/1/', '5/1/', '6/1/', '7/1']
SlotOff = ['4/0/', '5/0/', '6/0/', '7/0']

for i in range(1,3):

    InitialChecks[i] = ['Slot%i = 1' %i]
    InitialChecks[i] = str(InitialChecks[i]).replace('[\'', '').replace('\']', '')

    with open('lspci.sh', 'rb') as file:
        script = file.read()
    subprocess.call(script, shell=True)

    if Addresses[i-1] in open('results').read():
        result = ' '

        print("Device in Slot %d, checking to see what drive number it is..." %i)

        scan1 = ''
        # Initial disk scan
        os.system("sudo parted -l > scan1.txt")
        with open('scan1.txt', 'rb') as file:
            for line in file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "nvme" in part:
                        scan1 = scan1 + part
        print scan1

        # Disable the slot to get ready to record which drive number disappeared
        with open('removeslot%d.sh' %i, 'rb') as file:
            script = file.read()
        subprocess.call(script, shell=True)

        scan2 = ''
        # Initial disk scan
        os.system("sudo parted -l > scan2.txt")
        with open('scan2.txt', 'rb') as file:
            for line in file:
                for part in line.split():
                    if "nvme" in part:
                        scan2 = scan2 + part
        print scan2

        for nvme in scan1:
            if nvme not in scan2:
                    result = result + nvme 


        print("result is " + result)

        disk = filter(str.isdigit, result)
        strdiskchange = str(disk)
        diskchange[i] = int(strdiskchange[0])
        print diskchange[1]
        print("The new disk added to slot %i is /dev/nvme%dn1" %(i, diskchange[i]))

        # Rescan to re-enable the drive that was disabled.
        with open('rescan.sh', 'rb') as file:
            script = file.read()
        subprocess.call(script, shell=True)

        # Represents that Slot 1 is populated and on
        Slot[i] = 1
```

Here is the error output:

```
Device in Slot 1, checking to see what drive number it is...
/dev/nvme0n1:/dev/nvme1n1:
/dev/nvme1n1:
drive that disappear is 0
The new disk added to slot 1 is /dev/nvme0n1
Device in Slot 2, checking to see what drive number it is...
/dev/nvme0n1:/dev/nvme1n1:
/dev/nvme0n1:
drive that disappear is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUIArduino.py", line 75, in <module>
    diskchange[i] = int(strdiskchange[0])
IndexError: string index out of range
pciedev3ubuntu@PCIeDev3ubuntu:~/Documents$
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: See where it says `drive that disappear is `... You have an empty string, so `strdiskchange[0]` is an index out of range

Comment: I posted that I am aware of that, and that's why i'm getting the error message. But, the first loop through the string is not empty, and as you can see, the two strings I'm comparing for differences ARE different, so it shouldn't be empty from what I can tell, so that's the problem I'm trying to solve, not the error message itself.

Comment: This `for nvme in scan1` iterates over single characters in `scan1` string. I'm confused what you are expecting the `result` variable to become.

Comment: I think your `scan1` and  `scan2` should be lists or sets, rather than strings.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I believe I tried a list at one point, and received similar results. Is there anything specific I should set the variables inside the list/set to? because when I did it I just did scan = ['']*3.

Comment: Also, I had this working previously, except I was using the lsblk command instead of the parted command with no issues. lsblk ended up being troublesome with hard drives that were partitioned though, so I decided to give parted a shot. Same loop, same scans, just slightly different command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `tryCatch` function to ignore errors in a loop (such a blank or empty cell/vector) and continue where it left off

http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I went back to using the lsblk code that was working but just added the 'and 'p' not in line' portion to skip any lines that had a p since only partitioned lines contain a p.

```
    lsblk = subprocess.Popen(['lsblk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    scan2 = [line.strip() for line in lsblk.stdout if 'nvme' in line and 'p' not in line]
```

that just replaced

```
    os.system("sudo parted -l > scan1.txt")
    with open('scan1.txt', 'rb') as file:
        for line in file:
            for part in line.split():
                if "nvme" in part:
                    scan1 = scan1 + part
```